# Problems when trying to fill Xcode 10's icon requirements

Tags: xcode, xcode10

This is my first time using Xcode, so I'm not sure where else to turn. I have created an app and I'm trying to get it uploaded for Testflight, but I cannot due to Xcode asking me to fill all of the icon requirements.

I've used every generator and photo manipulation software I could get my hands on, but to no avail. Can I ask what everyone else usually uses to fill this criteria?

[image]

Comment: You are kind of overdoing this. The Notification, Settings, and Spotlight icons are optional. The regular icons are not optional, though, and neither is the app store icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying for iPad, add the icons. Otherwise, you can make the app just for iPhone, not Universal.

[image]

Also, you will certainly need the (original?) 1024 x 1024 image for the App Store.